# electron framework: record audio for input and output voice

Tags: javascript, electron, html5-audio, audio-recording

I am developing an electron application to record input and output audio of the device.

Is there any way to do that?

Currently, I am able to record the input audio and for that, I am using **navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia**.I got to know that this API does not allow to record output audio.